# Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have form that send data from form to another page by jquery like this:-

```
   <?
    $counter=0;
    $sqlmasmohType = mysql_query("select * from masmoh");
    while ($rowmasmohType = mysql_fetch_array($sqlmasmohType))
    {
        $counter++;

                        if($counter % 4 == 0){

                            $class= "no-margin-left";

                        }else $class="";
    ?>


    <div class="news-element <?= $class ?>"><input type="checkbox" id="masmoh" name="masmoh[]" value="<?=$rowmasmohType['id'] ?>"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=$rowmasmohType['name'] ?></div>

    <? } ?>  

<div class="clear"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="ft_user_id" id="ft_user_id" value="<?=$iduser?>" class="input-text">
    <input type="button" id="save_masmoh_user" name="save_masmoh_user" value="Save" class="custom-btn-train-parentt">
```

this form send to saveMasmohToUser page the 2 argument, one of this argument is Array and i need to save this Array to database like (1,5,p,55)

i will try this :-

```
public function saveMasmohToUser(){

    $ft_user_id = $_POST['ft_user_id'];
    $save_masmoh = $_POST['save_masmoh'];
    $unserializedData = array();
    parse_str($save_masmoh,$unserializedData);
    if($save_masmoh != ''){
        foreach($unserializedData as $unserializedData){
        if ($unserializedData != ""){
        $check = mysql_query("select count(*) as rowuser from masmoh_for_user where m_user_id = '".$ft_user_id."'");
        $rowUser = mysql_fetch_array($check);
        if ($rowUser['rowuser'] == 0)   
        {   
    $query = mysql_query("insert into masmoh_for_user (m_user_id,m_masmoh) values ('$ft_user_id','".implode($unserializedData, ',')."')");
        }
        else
        {
        $query = mysql_query("update masmoh_for_user set  m_masmoh = '".implode($unserializedData, ',')."' where m_user_id = '".$ft_user_id."'");
        }
    $newData = array();
    $newData['msg'] = "save";
    $data = json_encode($newData);
    echo $data ;
    }
    }
    }  


    }
```

but i will see this error :-

> Message:  implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

but when print Array `$unserializedData` its like :-

```
Array 
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

how can i solve this error.

Comment: `foreach($unserializedData as $unserializedData)` This did not strike you as a bad idea?

Comment: At first sight - implode takes argument in other order than the one you use.

Comment: @Cthulhu So what can i do ??

Comment: @zamalek100 Look answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
foreach($unserializedData as $unserializedData){
```

You can't use the same variable name as the one being `foreach`'d through. Change it so that the names are different, e.g:

```
foreach($unserializedData as $simpleData){
```

Note that you should also make the appropriate changes to your code when you do this. In this case, changing only this line should do the trick:

```
if ($unserializedData != ""){
```

Assuming that you used my example as-is, just change the above line's variable name to `$simpleData`. That foreach glitch also caused that implode error.

Note: according to PHP's documentation, `implode` accepts its parameters in either order. Although some users reported that you used the wrong order, it is irrelevant and your code should work with whichever order you want.

Comment: i will try your steps but the problem its still

Answer (score -1):

Your call to implode is backwards.

```
implode(seperator, array);
```

So you would use it like this:

```
implode(',', $unserializedData)
```

Comment: `implode()` takes an array as the second argument, not a string.

Comment: Thank you Sammitch no idea why I wrote string there. Just got back from a BSOD

Comment: @Sammitch see my code, i define `$unserializedData = array();`

Comment: @zamalek100 my comment was referring to Rottingham's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `<?php` instead of `<?`. I believe `<?` is deprecated. (If it is, i'll come back and edit this post.) Second, it shouldn't be erroring(if you're are passing an array as the second argument to implode).

**EDIT**

`<?` isn't deprecated, but you should still use `<?php`.

**EDIT 2**

Your call to implode IS wrong. The syntax of it is like this.
     `implode(seperator, array_to_be_seperated);`

Comment: If you are talking about the parameter order, `implode` accepts its parameters in either order.